# Script to show/hide tabs based on a cell value from a list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hoping to find a script that will look at a list of the tabs I have, if there is an X in the following column, then show sheet. Otherwise hide the sheet. On the sheet, the tab I am referencing is the last tab called "test" columns P:R. I have tried to piece together scripts from this forum but I am not having any success.

If this script is not able to be done I have the X populating on each week tab column AM2 if that would be an easier script. I still can't seem to figure even that out.

Below is the script to retrieve tab names

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lA_X_Jt31Jw9XreVThEhsWNWPK4umgltP_QalrZIfs4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

```
function hideshow() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('test');
  const shsr=6;//start row
  const rg=sh.getRange(shsr,16,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,3);
  const vs=rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r){
    if(r[2].toLowerCase()=='x') {
      ss.getSheetByName('r[0]').showSheet();
    }else{
      ss.getSheetByName('r[0]').hideSheet();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideSheet' of null (line 11, file "Show/Hide")Dismiss

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in your list of sheets.  Is your list in column 16?

Comment: I used your code above, only thing I chawed was 16 to 18.

Comment: Try it now.  Don't change anything

Comment: I'm still getting an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideSheet' of null (line 11, file "Show/Hide")Dismiss

Comment: I noticed that's an output of a custom function so the values are not really there they just appear to be so I tried getDisplayValues()

Comment: function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}

Comment: I then have a DATEVALUE column to change the sheet name to an actual date. The following column (18) is =IF(AND(Q9>='Full MP'!$A$2,Q9<='Full MP'!$B$2),"X","") to determine if there should be an X or not.

Comment: Post it in the question Please.